# jssor - [an error occurred while processing this directive] message

Tags: javascript, jssor

I'm using two jssor galleries, gallery_thumb and carousel, they both work fine but when I put them online I get this message:

[an error occurred while processing this directive]

Can't seem to find the actual problem since they both work fine, and this doesn't come up when I'm in local host...

Anyone come across the same problem?

The site is www.guitartech.fr

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code? I can't find any jssor or other javascript in your site. Only tracking.. and some other code where I would like to get some dinner and roses before you continue..

Comment: Oh my bad wrote it too fast, the site is actually www.guitartech.fr

Comment: Ah thanks, that is a much cleaner code! So it's working localy, but not online.. do you have a linux server online? Try giving the image folder recurvive rights like 0644, if this is not working try 0777 if this is working. I also found some solution like: "`- Files should be set to: 0644 (this is the UNIX file permissions)
- Folders should be set to: 0755`"

Comment: Thanks for answering and taking a look man, but there was just some issues with # that was slipped in comments.

Comment: Lol, ok. You shoul use the "I will answer my question myself" feature so people know which one is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in my code, some # in comments that created the error. 
All good now!